# Android Layout Direction issue in API 17

Tags: android, android-layout

I am going to build a Persian app (RTL). my app includes a Navigation Drawer.

I added in Manifest in application tag android:supportsRtl="true"

and in onCreate() method: getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

I know that LayoutDirection for less than 17 api does not work.

but icons (Toolbar & NavigationDrawer) in api 17 is reversed:

Result in API 22 (Correct):

[image]

Result in API 17 (Not Correct):

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="ir.mhborujerdi.mhb.ebook.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you put the xml for the swipe layout

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked a while ago, but if someone else needs a solution for this issue, **this will solve it**:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection( mRoot , ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR );
```

I hope it helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

having the requirement that API is minimum 17 is a little costly since it is not really old and still in use today...

I would like to suggest another way of pulling navigation drawer from right.

So, in your xml file you need to change that part,

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

if you set `android:layout_gravity="start"` to `"right"`, menu will be opened from right, and you can design the xml by orienting the right side always.

By this way you don't have to set the layout on `onCreate()` and API is not gonne bounded by 17+.

**update for toolbar**

instead of the default actionbar, as of lollipop we started to code our own `Toolbar` and you can put your own toolbar with the whole design determined by you. for toolbar example, Mohammad, I am pretty sure you can find more than enough by simple search

Comment: Thanks. but with this solution runtime error has occurs : 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT 
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1464)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your XML of NavigationView:

```
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
```

I hope it helps someone..